# Axios request to google/search?q=test return data in weird format rather than text/html

Tags: javascript, typescript, web-scraping, axios

If i try to request the link `https://google/search?q=test` using postman, it correctly return the html of result page

but if i try the same request using axios with same headers it return this encoded data

```
data: 'Öx1F�ÖbÖx00Öx00Öx00Öx00Öx00Öx02��;ir�F��åÖn' +
    é��k7O��Öx17- �1�h<cϾ�3�Öx15Öx13Öx05Öx14ˈÖx06Öx04�"�8�;��ዽ�*�n�aÖx7F��TԒ���ä֜SܦTÖb�ytv����ľ%z�Öbߔ�g�sZÖx10�ÖtH���Öx12?åö�Öx1C�uoÖx12Öx174��$Öx0B�0Öx16��̩%fԣYF��iÖx07��4?�3Öx12�a�Öx1F�I�G�?��u�kÜ�Öx18�ܯNÖx12%�Wåt�jÖx1A��Öx10Öx16t�fIj�ÖfÖf@/�"�gÖx05�Öx0BAÖx11�S'�Öx19�Öb?1P�Öx07ö�4w�0-�8�Öx1D@��7w�ϫ$���ö������ݧ��V���Ä�NÖx11&�P�öÖx07tY�Öx01e�nÖÖD�åÖx13׽XB�e�Ñh6Öx14�=Öx0FÖx0BQn���fI2���7$��Öx16$�i�;Öx1D����(��ÜÖx14t(�� Öné +
    '��(��dÖx12K�E˲��ä�5Öx06�=�R�B�ިKÖx12-�lO3����"�Xä�IÖx06����Öx19EÖx04�R�,�b(ɶ�Öx17I�Öx16ÖbGö�Öx0F(��&���NÖx14:�Öx0FÖx1D�Öx18Öx1B/�:Öx07E4Ȟe=Öx06Öx1C�GԔdm�Öx04�Öx12��AÖt��_Öx03Öx0FI��ÖbÖx0F�+NÖx02�1 ��Qr-�Öx12�_�ƻ��Ö'-%�!Q4,�0���U�SX�0v����ÖfÖx0E3Ö'�(f�Öx05�Öx15�SRP5NVCÖtÖx0F�k�jÖr���r�pÖx0Eö��Öx0E�t-G��2����dÖx0F�2��I�Sփ�3w0�N��Ҧ��g��*ǆ�6G/Öt"Ʈ���"E�zQ���Q��.+8ÖÖȬ�����4Öx11��j��KÖx1BÖx7F0�+U��+Öb�(Öx7F���Öx1F�ԁ��ÖrWEÖtqE9éWđQ3?��!mÖx1E���y���Öx03,��ҫ�Öx7FͯWÖx17�"�.�é���9Öx15Z4s�ͷ<3t�ÜÖx1A���H�Å��Öx16Tv)�Ä�@��nb1�f$����5�;NnD��>���Öx06��ȊÖx17Q�gÖr��@����Öx1A6��Öx1F J�����Öx1BK�3��ZÖx1C�U��fM�y�Ғȶ��sÖx19��Z�$tÖx05Ör��FÖx065m���BɅm�Öx1C���<YAq#)��"���Öx03���%Öx19�Öx99�ٲ!Öx19��<��éP5Öx00�Öf�Öx11��TeÖx04�.�"ȒÖx15(Öx10۪�Öx18����Ü�Öx02��Öx0BÖÖ)�Öx02�ÖtÖÖ�s��̹9�"Џ�ٞÖx0E4�Ör��Öx1AÅ������Z.csۢ������Öx17��Öx1CÖx04Öx10Öx15Öx12�Å����ב6�Öx110�V8��Öx12��Öx06�Öx17/Öx1AÖx1E�����Öx05P�ٷ��7�NC�?Öx15�%�d�y�üw4��åX�g���Öx16v�KZ��K����1�0��Öx17s�f&�2ЬÜ�5Öx0E�Öx1A�O����Öx11EÖx05j��Öx0E�S_�+��7�éÖx15�Öx06!ɁÖx13�Öx03Q�Qj�%����ʑ�dÖx00�Öx03��ˌÖx12�i.Öx155.��Öx1EU�jÖx02�!ä���K5O��Öx18�Öx7FĢt�Å�MÖx1CÖx89��<Öx15�Å�U�&�5M2��Iu���,bWÖx15����@>é!5���9Öx17BÖx18Öx0B��Öx06E�mÖx0FÖx17� V��Ü.�é��Öx00Å�<��Öx07eÖbt�Öx17ÖrA��p9��-ϋjÖx16�Z�Öx1AX���Öx1300�htööÖn' +
    '�:��_Öx04Hy���Öx03�lXB�����ꊣÖx04Öx0F&�2�̊Öx13IYÖx1BÖx14�9d�Öx07�2��E+N,Ön' +
    é�DOȡ�'0)�Q�ˑ$7�Öx0BÖÖ-�,"Öx02a@��Å����tÖx1B��Öx1C�N�ä,Ä�Öx1B�Öx01h���Jl�Öx1FnガÖx19Öné +
    'ÖÖÖx02��Öx00o��"m�uÅ��W���xÙÖx1F��3���llh@ь�<3Öx1DÖf��Öx0F�ȇ��#:�Öx01�.SK�I�Öx02Öx12V�uQt�E���n�$�F��ÄÖx03#t,��=����Öx17�vʮEA�8��Öx05�O�Öx10�PQ�Öx06�Öx134�Öx1D3Öx06�ÄAÖx05ÖÖU�"�Ön' +
    é��m�NÖx0F�Öb��Z܂�J6�Öx056�׉�Öx12�,@�Öx15�:I�$�Öx00���ʊ��a�Öx14$U��Öx0F"�)Öx14�0�mÖx02���UÖx1D,"1�aÖx0EÜ�ÄÖx03�غN��?Öx00S�m�7Öx00A�Öx19�RÖx19��ÖrÖx1CÖt>Ör��0Öx01���P<2Öx0F�Ä�d!��Ĺ��,�L6��w��'��DÖx10J@Öx113c�AG�4n��Öx14�üÄ䅡k�Öx7F�Öné +
    "��3�&cÖx13ÖÖuWYe$5�ǣ�i���Öx19j���ä�W�������<8jr�Öx15��Ör=ÅÖx0Bé����w��Pͬ�Öx1B�Öx00vHÖx0Bp�VFÖx10�.�K�����ü�TS�z�Öx00�TÖx05n.����Q$Öx0B'hé(k�,����m�üZÖx1EÖx1E�؛Öx1A����Öx14Öx107�Öx10�w�%�h���Öx0EÖx0E��Öx1CüSŦŊ�ج�(U��Öx1F�wÖx17�ÖÖ�é<���H;�Öx1EÖx11�ÖrA��Ä�Öx06#p��ϋ��_Ön" +
    'ÜÖx1DÖx1EÄÖx13�C@��(Öx01&�ÖrÖx07vÖx05��zÖn' +
    'Öb�rt��EÖn' +
    'N�C�Öx1F*qG���ϋ��-Öx00ÅÖx14��Öx18��3Öx19Öx1DO�I�Öx12�Öx17�̊��N"Öx17ÖÖé�äq�v�����T�ÅDv�ջD�+:,Г��Tb�KA�"t"�i�Öx01a�Öx11-շ��fä�.�Ԕ���o��ü���"é,_�ϵ�勉IÖx13�Öx1FE/�Öx11����RÅ/��v6Öx0FA�Öx02�H�Öx15IÖx17�fÖx0EnöÖx183��<Ön' +
    '��Öx18�.����Öx19���/Öx1F�l���Öx0E�0W�2.t��ːÖx13����Öx1B�<Z�Y��Öt��Ġ�QöoF�.1�̠�,�Öx11a%cz.Öx03�p�Öx1Bx�Å���јÖx1EW��2�O���awÖx05K(Öx18�,Öx1A��э��Öx0F�G�Öx1FÖx1A�7v�S�xZ"J�(�Öx03�Öx1F03�-1(��88X�V�j�&�Öx7F0��ÖbK<�Öx00�Öx02�ÖÖpjP�DÖx01�drÖrü�Öx7FFcPS�$Ön' +
    '�$Öx05��Öx01ä�Öx1F�SQpn�%Ön' +
    'Öx19�L�Öt4n�Öx06Öx07�T���6PÖx0E*0�wÖn' +
    '�!Ĥ��HÖx18��8��cÖx01üÖx1AÖx18x�Öx0EI-�Öx11�oA#���oZpҳÖx1F �Vsg��a�aÖräÖx13Öx1B�Öx02�EÖx13�1�t&��ɮ���Z�Öx03Öx02�Öx1B�Öx07�uÖn' +
    "?ÅIÖx1DI��,�1z�Öx1C�ΙÖx1B.75����Öx02��9��Öx04�;=��Öx0B�ͅGu:e��Öx1F�3Öx04���8y�b�J)��mj4�Öx13�?�R�ÖÖ�Öx1B���aZÖx14x=ÖÖ�Vl�ڭ��SÖx7FÖx00Öx02�-3g2��Öx15�%&Öx05-��W�C������я��Öx1B�V.�ÖÖx�����H՚�ÖÖA1b�&L3����幽�ë��hՅ����TÖx7F��V�d�=éۙ/�0�؉äÄkN��Öx10�)�ܜ��DÖx18�S��sإ���,éZ�Λh���������k���#N5F�Å��dÖx05���Ü�Öx14���Öx03ޡ��h��é��Fm-e5���lä�j���מӒ@Öx1FÖx036�Öx00�(̙Öx00ü@�����M�6�'�Ör�@����ém�4�Ǉ�Ko�vÖx03�9��Öx07<��Öx17��sÖb�ASÖx06y���W��Öx01wÖf�Öx03Öx17Öx13��Er��Z:�Öx17��$���Öx1EJÖx00�Ü�Ön" +
    "����FÖx1D�=؃Öx01O�Öx10Öf��u�_��ÜP'm�/��mKGM��H�h�mÖx1B��oÄ��<�:�nÖx0FK�Öx14��)0䀑Öx0E�LeO��q�o=�2r;Öx04�/x�ǰ�H�Öx03kdÖx06��#f��/��0Öx03B�z�2����Öx0E���J%iÖx1A�®�T�Öx04b�w�éÄ�X�>Å*p�L�!Öx11F�<��J��Öx1C��<�Ā���*�S��5#Öx10�B�iWg�)�A���FEXÖx13́��9%51Öx1C Öx06�q1݀��K�Ön" +
    'C�:��TTQtü���DådZ,UÖ'"y�����6�YnL����l�Öb1�(���Öx16���Å,Öx1B�ɷ��Öx1F�Öx07��r��KÖx05Öbs�3��ö!KÖx16$�s���!�Öx0E�:m#Öx05��sR8����Öx0F�Öx07>Öx1CÖx07�t��N-�G�-Öx01YZZ;I�Öx02�.�G�W�é�!c�Öx06�Öx1B���c�x��X��!���4Öx1C��Y��Öx10�Öx7FK�x(Ön' +
    '"��Öx1B�_5�_�Öx15�$k�A,�C�Öx05��Oö,�̈Öx01��Xi�c��%@�Öx1A�rI��K"����$Öx0B��&7ü��u�鍽a=V$/�Öx15��!Ön' +
    '���Öx03N��HÖx0Fȅ�S8ÅÖx17H3�1Öx0B��Öx16b��鍽��₭äÖx04"C�n��P3�L�Öx11��YÖx15Öx02Öx13&w���w���ۅ��띢����Öx1B��U�z�LaÅ�f�m%�äz���Ӂ�Öx1E�9ܔ��Öx02�@x&�Öx1B����Ön' +
    '+����"����>Öx14�X٩�Öx01�pd���rƃ�K��&pa�0ĐS��8wmrI&��H5�1�Öx13�E����iۥ3K��Öx0EPÖn' +
    'EÖx12�A0���_�Öx1F���Öx13������gP���B�"6�s0��Öx10��Öx7F�aÖx0E0Öb���"Q�v�,�Öx0F�Öx19>�Öx00�;8� ä �/�Öx1An��Öx11Öx19��:��BEk�Ä.cÖx7Fd,�9Öx01�å Ön' +
    '�ph����SÖx1B���K��hQ��H���=K���OÜÖx15$�Öx0B@�ÖÖƳ��C�Öx06�g=t!�pYn��/Öx05�jÖn' +
    'Öx7F�Ör�����Öx0Ek(��C�ʋ���8O@��ǋ��Öf���dÜ�aTËʩÖx19�x��5ه��5�ٰw�MM©�fM�Öx00�Öx07���r�IvVöiVö�Vö�ä<�ԭ�äM�b=�Öx05F��<�Öx19i0kZÖx06�Ä�H�YӪVlaFÖx1EŌt1��Öx12�Öx1Aå� uÖx0B淂�z��=I u��Ön' +
    'Öx0B�Öx1Af_�H��KÖx1D�Ä�RD�v�LO�vÅ�����e�x���jO���G����ÄÜȧ�ép�üS�N�Öx1C����ÖÖ��B�Öx19Öx19"K����Öx10SÖx1A��bo���ٌm����0����é��1�ÖfÖx14b����äÖf�c2Öx10O-�ö�ѯÖx11S�Ď�WqÖx7F�_Öx1C�Öx0F+���d>��9p�Öx05�.���_Öx15rdÖx17�BÖf��2Ön' +
    '�M�3�o;j�UÖx14�V�9Öx15ϐÖx14Öx10Öx04��ܚƴe���Öx0B���S�xÖx06���Öx15Öx01WÖx14�Öx0Ei1é��.Öx06��Q5���x�Öx03� J�Å�nWXi���sQé8Öx1F�EÅÖx17-���Öx01��8�K��dÖx05��Öx1B�@Öx1C>��HZ?X��ü�����Öx1C8��Öx7F��ȁ�Öx0FÖx06AänԒACQ$)üÖx07�E�ZÖ'��Öx7F��ü�φ6Öx03$;���Öb+���YD�Öf⎚Öx16�Ö'Öx03 8���Öx1CÖx19�ȃa�Öx19f���p��1n�Öx7FÖx06�ʿX���A�Öx19ÖfÖÖÖx15��:�yٙ���.s���Öx11Öx10i"JÖx0Fh�֑��Öx01Q_�bV���;��ұÜ����x���+Öx10#Öx7F��Eé�fp���Öx06Ö'��BÖx07Öx1C0�.�7Öx0F�Öx04�ÖÖÜ���ÖbxeT$bÅÖn' +
    '��Öx14��Öx0EtÖn' +
    'Q�Ät�Öx03d��Öx17WV�n�9�aÖx1D8@�Öx1B�Örö؀=��ÖÖ��ö��Öx0EX��Öx06��V��l�07c��������;�Xʪ��Öx19��té���9m�#ÖtÖx0E�(�Öx13��R�k���N�Ö'Öx17�e�Ä�G׆��Örü��a��G_Öx1B����üå�N)��Ör�>���@�D���Öx19��Ör�dÖx07b�6�ä�Öx18��+�ö�_pe�ϸR���cO�aJ"�5�6���=��9��D�Öx00Mbö��&ȑH��ÖtÖx19:��Öx0E#���C�����!Öx1E�ԨK�Ör��a�Y�Öx0BÖx18�A�9=����b�Öx079�Öx17Ea�Öx01�7�VX3Ö'Öx16�%Nåd�C��ÅÖb�!ħ2�d�D�äjyÖx10Öx14nÖx07��lġ�O@�eÅb�Xü�Ö'Öx0F�U�j_b�5u���Öx06�Öx02Öx018��Öx1Ej4FÖtxÖx01��äƌ�Öx11bY���Öx07r6Öx02�Öx13�<���ÖÖÖx19��Öx12�X�Ö'�����C��b��o�k��J�Kfå�Ör�#��*Öx1CÖx00KÖx19Öx0EÖx06Öx1F��Öt:�xhÖx17û&����Ör��J��é�<Öx10y>#,�(�O���kmÖ'���Öx7F�bn.N�����ÖfÖf��Öx1D>��4��k�����Öx15ӟ��zO*Öx1A)��ȍ8_BÖx7F�JÖx1A���l!Öx17�>"�Öx7FmÖx13(��J�8�U2Öx7F�ÜÖx0EÖx0B�;tn��ä!�Öx12��gö�iDV+�����Ön' +
    '��߳Öx05����=Ü��p�6��0��.��Öx0FIݬÖx133Öx19���㹧�Öx19Ön' +
    'f�LLC9�C��üD4Öx13Öx05q�6éZÖtG,Öx01Ysa�wO�/Öx1F��gy�Å�Öx1B.Öx05�7�Öx02�� ��Öx12Öx01_fY��,Ö'��Öx01���B0L�O�ÖÖ�£���z��>zÖx12���G����Öx17���s�ݛ�Öx7F����T ���Ȋ�JDlL����b�d�TAÖx0F�Öx0B���(,C����%b�f:�Öx04�h��JOF�iS�<<Öx11�4uÖx12Öx1D�6WN��:%�Caz��Öx16AW�#er���ÖtV!Oy�6��d2Öx1Ec�Öx14Öx0B�GÖ'�nz���x�˦�ÖtB����@<�v�ÖtÖx072:��Öx15Öx10ÖÖ3�Öx1Eo�Öx195k��sď��i�3>х�I�ÖtG�HÖx19ÖtÖx1AÖx11�j;RƬö�LO�Ѥ%Öx04ÄƊ(,F�Öx1D���Öx13r<Öx05lÖx11�d4Öx16�Öx11�q��EÄ���S�D�u��G�x���:��2:y5Տ���H9Öx1C��ۇ9��Ör�Öx05�Öx1EÖx10�Öx01���/�"�TöÖx15Rw�GÖx0B"+��X�a���_Öx15,Öx1C۱��X�%���Öx1C�Öx17��Öx1Ep���߇�MÖn' +
    '�Öx1A�U?��6pYʍU�@��Öx05��;Z�=�M�)�Öx1D�Ön' +
    '�W���Öx1B CÖn' +
    '��Öx04Թ�D����Öx0FÖx0BsÄÖ'Inv��Öx0E����Öx0EÖx07���Öx7FwÖt���xo�7�60���Öx195���-�<>Öx05Öx1AxÖx15��8��N��ph�"������Ötf7Öx16ҋ)Öx1Dv=��ھ��Z9Ör��gӯ_�Öx16�O�Öb�v?��f��,�öÖx015RÖx14�BoÖx16������X?ü+0h�Öx01Öx15Öx19�Öt�iSJgE�Z�Öx04�x�WkÖx17�Σ�fA�VA�Öx7F�öÖx16:!2������Öx00_Öx02�Öx12�O.�Öx14���ÖÖÖx16�é���Öx07���S�Öx0BÖx7F�Y����Q7�B��?���Z"Öx1F�����Öx01Öx00Öx00���ÄåO�8Öx18�*V��4Öt�����FbÖf*N�uÖx1C�n�Öx7FPH�éH�.Nڕ��e���Öx1A�/6?����Öx13��TÖx01�Öx1D⟟w7?�@Y�E��Öx0BZÖx16��Ör�Öx14öÖtio�N$���$)H0�éÖfd�Öx06��e��Öx1C;Öx17/Öx1F��"�Öx04��x�$�4�l��Öx01�vöÖx1B�Å���Öx1Cus2�xK���yb�Öt�E.F��dw��ԩ�lÖtÖx19�o�l���FE�åWÖx13����0����H�Öx02�p��lÖx06֌��Ör<�aäÖx1B�$�Öx17���᯺���3�Öx1C�J�jH��MguaP��0��Öx03�Öx15��PnÖx1F�Öx1A���Öx1BÖx18�tÖx1E�zʹ��,��;˙C���Öb���äUF�L��ü<��v��p���9Jb�3�<"�#sY�&���Öt%�3vÖx7F����O�C��Öx1CrÖx16��Öx0E�=��F�Q��"�Jt�Öx159i�o�Ö'm�Öx15)�aW�@�F�aöd+J�akGÖx14ݏ�Öx1D+qW��+�����GWÖx11ÖÖ��?�"h-Öx17D ��k+���J��$q�UéwÖx15Öx13�Öx14�@S,Öx06�Öx8BåÖx02Q&�Öx0FÖ'�Öx7FÖx1C����8+fI���5�8�A%�NÖ'OBJ���1�,��U&mÖn' +
    '���c�*��aÖx0E;�Öx18W�öÅ��8ÖÖ"F�XK�j�*-OÄCÖx0B�Ä��RU%�:��Öx12Öx11�%"�׿+���4S�b����b��Öx0B2�q��Öx14Öx0F*BÄÖx0BeÖn' +
    é�>Qk-T>�F0�ZÖx1Eqc�Y6hjO*Y6WÖx05.���p��M�#J���"ÖrW����ܮ�Öx19�ƶޤJV�͝��&�ɪ��n���ǔ�-Wr܂Öx0FASÖx11Öx07KÖx15ÖrÖx11Öx11�P��KxÄW*�EÖx10��@����Ρ���1�Öx1Aj��'��wt�uQ�DÖx0FYÖb?Öx0FY�Öb!J��xB">�X��@���ÖÖ��p"(�E�&�H�t���B��V<̴��Uɥ���Z�NÖx1A����ߓ-Öx1E��Öx1B.!�ådÖx19���:S1�0�Öx14�Öx04�ZpK��å��Öx13-b�N%h��(��!(Öx164Öx0BÖx17��'�t%oÖx11���d�f�q8Öx1E���6VJÖtm����Ör�&n��=<t�x��<Öt9��0-����Ör�;s��C�WÖné +
    '��QMÖx16<�Öx1COr4I�*�Ön' +
    ')��כ�O+��Öx0B�gÖx16=��yXߏz���$�>?�cÄ6Öx7F�Öx14�-�Öx17�.Ör3;��p��Öx05�+wFܐ�sS��gQQe�z����V�f�ҸÖx1C�Öx00#�Öx16:�l��Aݟw�m:�͵k�åv�Ü�Öx1DÖx05�g���C��y��*ÖtÅr�&���b�8�l�Öx00��I��%���_Öx11(ä9���H/KÖx12e.l�_P�AÅ�ÜÖx01)Öt��Öx05幬��h��Ön' +
    'Öx7FÅ��/L0ÖÖE�Ö'��<W� ;Öx7FÖ'�WÖ'�yö��vME�s�Öx1ENc���-%�*���yÖx1C�oÖx00Öx00Öx00���ÖÖÄs�:Öx10�+�OÖ'g@c�����Öx19B(!qڐ�@Öx1E�%�Ör�Öx1AÖx07L<���Ͷn&<�!Öx01��JÜKڛ�իvdI�Öx19J�G��>�Gpå���Q2ꃞ��%.I�Öx7FÖÖ��;�IA�Öx03���Öf�����?Öx7F�éÖx01c���V��Z�ߑ���3�YÖx17��Öx06��Q����IÖx00s��c��Öx1AÖx05�P��ۿÖx17S? r��Öx0BÖx18Öx0Bx<b+Kp�b�Ü�Öx0B/X�Öx15��"n���!�Öx1DÅ���Öx7Fu�9Ͽ6��p�ݸ���Öx11�;Öx01��Öx00AÖx18��,Örړ�ۻv�#��T�v���P@�T��bÖx0EÖx02�v��aÖx0E���Öx10F�ͪ�i�ö��⛲��Öx1Fh�G����Öx15OA�F�6v��VÖx00?Zo)Öx1D�Öx0EzÖx10e�$��c-���h�!åkV�Z�Öx13��<��Öx185�Y��v�F�(ǂ�Ö'Öx1A�Öx19X���)Öx1D�Öt�Öx97��Öx02�Öx07�ݯ�����sÖtPH�$Öx012nÖx06�*��e�Y*���v��4Ü��,_j�i���h��?д�Öx12�Öx7F�� #Öx04YD0�Öx03���Öx05Ü��ä�,����m<? Y.�ÖÖ���.ٯ Öf,�/�IÖx03Iѭ�/����H�d�Öx1EcX�8ߺȫ�����Öx05G�NÖx1A�Qʃ�q��rW�w�Öf8e0�Öx1B�56�äö(M�p�Öx10�(å�uÖx10Nh�%S<D��MÖx19TU�9�-Öx1DBÖf�P��ڍbÖx18A�h�Öx0BW��zÖx0Bl��åÖx1E�Öx13�fw�Öx15�Å+�Öx01öptޜz���Öx04�,Öx0Bf�Öx00�t@k�TÖt�_V�5é7��W���Öx0E�O��Մ�r�˶�Öx04�_��Öx1C/Öx16WȊ�Ö'Ä�Öx11�Öfi��<<�åĀ��Vc/Öx15�ÄShRۏ�Ǩ�E�Öx14r��!��Z��*R�Öx01å4��Öx06Öx1B�1�8ÖtY�C�Y��qxÖx1D�é�Y"��Z�Öf�Öx03���G�pӷ�qz�p���sÖ'EÖx19 ��:�Ön' +
    "8�*�h2f�Lz����r؆�WG�Ör�t�d'meFi������&_�45�������Ä��ÖbA���s��nÖf�>Öx15RT�Q�i쳑��d���L�Öx02W�CÖx1BÖx1E��å$椔Öx1C�G��X�Q�Öx024Öx0BO<�i�2�,V����Öx02�h���Ön" +
    é��<<t=�I��>��5Öx03D���Y�����Öx00KM�N���H��wSMÖx10�GOÖx17�����Öb�6�M�FÖx1B�Öx04�ä���E�Ä$�eÖx01��hiÖx13Öx10üD�N:f�-Öx03���1zÖx00L�p���1��QÖx02ü��6ty�Öx11Z8D,"�Öx1A��V�Öf'��7�UÖx10Lpü��7��6��TÖbÖné +
    "Öx05��Öx13և�'�4��Öx06���ö����Y��-��3s��AÖx0FÖt�2��<��poD-���Öx01Öx00Öx00���ÖÖ�r�@Öx10�Öx15_S��@D%�Öx144hTTÖx16�&oÖx12Öx06�éT���wÖx18ééf:&Ä�勥̵ä�O�4GÖn" +
    '���tÖx0BxÖr�m�ö3tە���Öx16�*����A���9L�G�/��3QÖx06DF��Գ��OÖfÖx14�Öx1A��eÖx7FUw�2����Ön' +
    ")�N��8�Öx02Öx18��m�Öx1D�Öx03Öx13�Öx10��æ݈��/��fvÖx1E�!�Z/Öx13�eÖx1E���68��_�m�Öx03k�DybCW�Öx0E�?Öx10KN��C��Ns��ÖbÖx12Öx03c��Öx02�J؇7Öx0FÖx1F��Öx00W�J���*ä�O*qåc�Öx126@��TÖx15�K�&@V?Y���s���f����ÅhÖx0EÖx19cG)OÖbC-ÖbÖx1E�Öx15�ä��Öx1Fä+Öf�/ö����Öx06YÖx18Ü�qåÖx14����>��EJ�B��ȷ�LՋ/��7�äӪ�+Cv߸��Öx02�Öx10 Öf�'���(x4Öx05B4Öx02O/�=8�Öx1F6�.�����ö<b��v�J��#�3Z�qeÖx10Öt���Y��Öx7FÖfäp�oZ��3�U�jfT.Öx04?fz��fl���Öx11�Jå��,tᦓ��U6p�Ör駾�,z����nzBeC�������<<� �Öf��%Öx0B�WGÖx1EIkÖx17d:�Öry��7Öx01:Öx14��ð��AÖx7F2�J�K�x����)����Öx00e��l�ޢ�ÖÖÄ�ö�ÖrÖx07Öx1BކÅ?zߢÖx13��Öx1CÄ<q�X�����EcÖÖÖx04�yÖx16?��V�Öx0E�Ön" +
    éÖx00&�XÖx12DöƑQ��������)��i�Ä!LZWɑe��D��XfÖx7F�IPC0f��%x��"�!Ԣ��Z#!Öx12Öx00ŔlÖx7F�Öx00�x�Bp�Ü@m'Öx0E1/��m��a±DO�Öx12����x��#��Öx1Dt�Öx16�2nq6äJÖx1D1��vk��_�Öx10jd�ׇ�iB�KR�#��Öb�i�Öx12��_�����Öx0BÖx1D���Q��4�Öf,�A��Öx02�Öx15ϛR�Öx06Fr��toÖr�,��H���6U�Öx0E��ÖÖ�p����_��Öné +
    '�"Öx15��y88G!Öx04��Öx04�п��u_;�B:Ä@��̽���äÖx11Öx12Öx03�0 TjjÖx07���KÖr��Öx1Aز֜�I��Öx00 皴�C3��ÖÖ��Ön' +
    "�ȇÖx12�Q��ÖÖ���+BƂtÖx12�hÖx02���u��S�PN�t�åكF��VAÖx1E9�0dJ�<Z��Öx1B�'Öb����/Öx00Öx00Öx00���å�r�ʖ���Ön" +
    'Y;�Öx05mI �x�TÖx0E�)��l�k��vkH@���Öx060.;��s�Öx07��SÖx11��FtD?Öx1E�����Örw�LIÖbÖf�k����� R9�ÖÖS�ÖÖ��y�ωb��y���(&�L�Öx1EÖx13;���>�2�ͅ)��l�c�ö�Öx19>Öx1E�������;�3�?�l�<�Öx12"�i�8Y�n�Öx03T��O��7��Öx00�Öx16Öx1EÖx0E��nÖx0FOÖt����&�Öx7F���Öx7Fr�w�%�Öx06���Ѭ=Ö'p9?�å��Öx0F��Öx04΀gt���Öt��1&��"fs��P�Öx04Öx1E:��-Öx10�m����O��Öx15ÄX����FÖx00M���?<�ÖtЙ�zÖx0E/�D��T���%�O��Öx1F�B�ˏ���:�Öx00��Y%ä��ap̦Ö'�g����égÖx1B.��7Öx11F�Öx1Bԁk�Öx11<��ÖÖ�/Öx14����!چ>f�֮�D>�Öx18é�RAÖx0F�<"5Åh�n�ڪ�Öx12/�Öx04=YWM/�#�,-Öx15V����CÖx1Bٯl�Z)�Öx0E�̽#�ZJy�Öx7F�Öx0Er�Öx1F�Öx1BäM�diXÖx1F,�sü�z����N�4�ÖrwlÖx18�rl�$v��XÖn' +
    '�p(�����q�Öx016Öx1FÖx1C���_n�üj�v�l�ÖÖx��Fb�8���Ä��Öt�3�tÖx10���g���YÅ��Ön' +
    '�_Öx7F�_nl:hJ4%�Öx07#�dw�U �Öx19�IzÖx0Fh��ǈo$��r$0,�3�cÖx0F�wI��Öx1E�M$��x��ĳ��޳�F��x��8�l��Öx03Öx1E�,WlÄ��Öx15_Öx1DM�m��Öt�Öx1E�RÜü���Å,����züä�aP��NÖf�1�M��éo��dÖn' +
    '�Öx12%m�>�j��<zx!�GÖ́éÖx1EAäÖx1AR�C��X?ۺy@Öx02�-Öx19��PåӕÖx06f��Öx11�TipÅ��iD�-�Aއ���ĜdO�Öx0E쫜Z�Öx1E�Öx1D�w�Xz�)�Öx0F�n�Ö'�= ÖfN�����Ör�6v�o�Öx19Öx1A�����o?Öx01Öx00�Öx19j�pY��5��1Öx02g�F��I�R*�Öx14��H�k�s���/Öx14��ȻCЩ��=��9�Öx10p�KÖx05*�Öx13�Öx0FD��yTrÖx1A$��Öx03x�.Öx15��/�Öx07�Öx02��Öx105mÖx1D�eÖx19/��)Öx1F�ezÖx1A��4�KQ��ýl�Öx05Y��Öx1EÖx10����G+N�YU���MD�NÖÖM�,Öx13�Öx14����A�le��Öx1D�Pt�Öx06Öb��Öx1E�-B�Öx16Qw��!�+��6�8ÖÖÖ'��Ze�ÖÖ�#N+�vÄ��=ߨx�F�N��Öx03<Ör�mECf��<�Z��7��ÖÖÖx1C.�Öb��2�%M�H� Öx1Ce���Ör�Å>,��k�r� ��Ör�Öx16����r�Z�)�Öx7F��ÖÖ.�*Ör��Öx1F(JLå��K�0�o�y�ovöɀ.��<G�B2�ågÖx06�JNÖx12Öx05c���Öx15؞c��I��Dü��ä�q�Å@��c�qÖx06��&����A��=uö�O���*��="lT��a���A��U�b���:Å�E�6Öx1C�6Öx0B�8zÖx14 Öx0F�t T��@���E�<��Öx0EXÖt��_e����<�å�Ä��᣼BÖx07�ü<Öru�ä��r�V-�"��RC��kK�6öÖx7F���W��ügBWÖb�M#HÖ'Öx05�,m�˙�Öx13RÖt�Ön' +
    '�LK��jÖtr���Öx15k���Ä���Öx15t�Öx17ÄÖx17;OKKHEԓ��Ön' +
    "���Öx17?_w����t����8�K��JÖÖ�Öx02Öx07��.�����$å3��'�Öx1E�Ku�#��@Öx1F�ܥ���Öx7F��;��Ön" +
    '�7�����Öx1F���O��(y�+�oOéÖt؎S���U�(Öx1Bs����äN��es7��ܮc�M���?���z�jÖn' +
    '�Öx1C���N�a�Öf�zÖx0EÖx0FMX�2#XÖx1FÜ�Öx12�JÖx7F�:Öx06ö��Öx1CÖrä�߾��G�IÖfOyéQ$�����o?�@�Öx07�Öx10Uü�پ��Wo6%�F��?��Y��wÖt���nj�T2z��Öx03P�Öx19P���SU��Öx1Au�����$Y��é�M���ޭxÖx17���råϿ_gHL�öWk@��T��Öx04.�&�#�VO_ö�,����n��� Öx7F��<Öx1A.��Öx02��ݲéÖx11�% �T/e��Å��Uä������&���Ö'�éÖx02$a�OÖx05Öx1AÄ��r�/Öx03�Öx1DÖx03���.Öx0FÖx0E�=ר5N��Öx13�����Öx11��U��Ӓ�h?�z�Öx18Öbb�&ü&<��Öx19�Ü�büs��V��/jYR��8x/Öx1F�Üü2�Öx1E�Öx18�Ͼ�Öx01Öx19����Ö'g�X���j�Q�RÖx07å�ÖÖ��kY��Z�R/�Öx03å�Öx0E��"Öx7F�6p웖�+nÖx04:/�E�;Öx1E'... 35316 more characters
å
```

**Response header**

```
'content-type': 'text/html; charset=UTF-8',
    date: 'Thu, 24 Nov 2022 11:44:15 GMT',
    expires: '-1',
    'cache-control': 'private, max-age=0',
    'content-security-policy': "object-src 'none';base-uri 'self';script-src 'nonce-wBodLT_mypP-wVqhEOjplA' 'strict-dynamic' 'report-sample' 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline' https: http:;report-uri https://csp.withgoogle.com/csp/gws/xsrp",
    'cross-origin-opener-policy-report-only': 'same-origin-allow-popups; report-to="gws"',
    'report-to': '{"group":"gws","max_age":2592000,"endpoints":[{"url":"https://csp.withgoogle.com/csp/report-to/gws/xsrp"}]}',
    'bfcache-opt-in': 'unload',
    p3p: 'CP="This is not a P3P policy! See g.co/p3phelp for more info."',
    server: 'gws',
    'x-xss-protection': '0',
    'x-frame-options': 'SAMEORIGIN',
    'set-cookie': [
      'SOCS=CAAaBgiA6PqbBg; expires=Sun, 24-Dec-2023 11:44:15 GMT; path=/; domain=.google.com; Secure; SameSite=lax',
      'AEC=AakniGOwhDyqGaKGESxzi8Qzz5ejK02OGZ_c2T_oAi3cTjVPp1QuEXabgQ; expires=Tue, 23-May-2023 11:44:15 GMT; path=/; domain=.google.com; Secure; HttpOnly; SameSite=lax',
      '__Secure-ENID=8.SE=FxUcD9jAY4XVc2kVsGzvuOo3vIsAZQNhsM9_VGFl47ALwohAOiaTxreeeKBjpV5BBDCobEfUNTa45zfGDyRr8i9RtOKCe6LeS1BEf-dd-76FBAJZDIpuKqMncIZNxJ0FIJZ66yCD_G1kIaLBmgejro_l-79IXjji91hZwDusqaw; expires=Mon, 25-Dec-2023 04:02:33 GMT; path=/; domain=.google.com; Secure; HttpOnly; SameSite=lax',
      'CONSENT=PENDING+337; expires=Sat, 23-Nov-2024 11:44:15 GMT; path=/; domain=.google.com; Secure'
    ],
    'alt-svc': 'h3=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-29=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q050=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q046=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q043=":443"; ma=2592000,quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="46,43"',
    connection: 'close',
    'transfer-encoding': 'chunked'
  },
```

Reproduction using replit : https://replit.com/@SqualliKarim/WorthlessStarkArchive#index.ts

Comment: used unirest, returned correct data, so there must be something with axios config?

Comment: Can you us the `request using axios` your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### In v1.2.1 fixed this error.

try this code

```
axios.get("https://google.com/search?q=javascript",{ headers: { 'Accept-Encoding': 'text/html; charset=UTF-8',}}).then(response => console.log(response.data))
```

The axios's default Accept-Encoding is gzip.